# How should I pull changes replace my local main to remote main on github?

Tags: git, github

I have local main in my system and it has some folders which are deleted from remote main and now I want all changes from remote main to my local main but when I did ""git pull"" or "git pull origin main" it still has that folder which is deleted already from remote main. so what should I do here??

Comment: inshort i want to replace my entire local main with remote main and i dont want any extra files from my  local main

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+replace+master+remote

Comment: `git fetch && git checkout main && git reset --hard origin/main`

Comment: I already did these steps but it still keep that one empty folder in my local main and does not remove it by itself as the remote main doesn't have it . Although, i think that the rest of the folders gets updated with the ones in the remote main.

Comment: What says `git status` about the folder?

Comment: it says added new folder and wants me to add new folder. Also there has been some changes done in naming of folders in remote main but still i couldn't see them in my local main when i pull changes